# How to build a Flex FormItem with an image button in the label section?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I want to build a flex FormItem extension that adds a button into the item label section, such that there is both a text label and, to the right of it, a button that uses an image icon:

[A form item http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/4411/screenshot20100730at331.png](http://img830.imageshack.us/img830/4411/screenshot20100730at331.png)

Basically, I want to create that 'i' icon, such that I can click on it to display a help overlay for the item in question.

Is there an existing component that does this? If not, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use grid, gridrow, and grititem, like the html table. and add the label and the "i" image into a horizontal layout container inside the griditem.

Comment: While that'll technically _work_, it doesn't allow for drop-in replacement in existing Forms; I'd have to re-build many components to use it. No, I need a FormItem or something that behaves like a FormItem for this.

Comment: Chris, There is no such form item in flex as far as I know. Also you can extend the flex formItem and create your own, but again you will have to replace it in all existing places.

Answer (score 0):

See

http://kennethsutherland.com/2009/05/27/formitem-adding-an-icon/